# Base 10 is better than Base 12 or Base 16

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

Transcript:

```
82 28 a8 8a a8 8a 87 78 a8 8a
20 03 20 36 1a a8 7a bb a7 bb
20 a3 62 31 6a 81 a7 bb bb 7a
02 60 32 13 a6 8a 97 79 97 bb
02 56 26 63 16 58 7a a9 bb a7
50 63 63 5a 56 18 57 9a a4 74
50 06 a0 51 a6 1a 75 49 bb 7a
5a 6a bb a5 16 bb 95 9a 49 bb
a5 bb bb 5a bb bb a5 bb bb a4
5a bb bb a5 bb bb 5a a4 4a bb
```

Hint:

> There will never be a [visual](/questions/tagged/visual) tag in this post.

> Title is a hint as well.

Additional hint:

> No number appears twice in the same box.

> Ignore `a`s and `b`s, and look at each digit individually.

Partial solutions and ideas are welcome in either the comment section or the answer section.

Comment: Ooh, tetrominoes! Given that there's no color guide, I assume it's an irrelevant detail…

Comment: Yep... tetris is a redherring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> **SNY SMARTIE**, your username!

> Hint says there will never be a [visual](/questions/tagged/visual) tag for the puzzle, so the colors are probably irrelevant. The title says "base 10 is better than base 12 or base 16", hinting that we should only look at the numbers used in base 10.

The right idea is to

> Look at each number individually on the grid. Each group of cells that have a specific number form a shape that look like a letter!

See this grid:

> [image: completed grid] 
>  1s are connected in orange and gives **S** 
>  2s are connected in yellow and gives **N** 
>  3s are connected in green and gives **Y** 
>  4s are connected in cyan and gives **S** 
>  5s are connected in light blue and gives **M** 
>  6s are connected in purple and gives **A** 
>  7s are connected in dark blue and gives **R** 
>  8s are connected in dark gray and gives **T** 
>  9s are connected in light gray and gives **I** 
>  0s are connected in red and gives **E**

> Putting the letters in 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0 order gives the answer: **SNY SMARTIE**!

Comment: Exactly right! Colors are for aesthetic purposes.